# How to map json data with java class if its changs, sometimes data chages jsonArray to JsonObject in response

Tags: android, json

I am getting Json Response from the server, And mapping JSON data with Java class.
Here is code.

```
 Gson gsonObj = new Gson();
 AppointmentData    appointmentData = gsonObj.fromJson(response, AppointmentData.class);
```

its working fine until response changes sometimes.
Here is response screenshot.
[image: Json Response from the server]
Now look at the response final_slots in response is sometimes as JSON Object and sometimes JSONArray. if final_slots is JSONArray then my Mapping code works, but if its is JSON Object then I have to change the logic. here is my code what I m doing in both cases

```
   JSONObject JsonObjResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONObject jsonDataObj = JsonObjResponse.getJSONObject("data");

                Object json = new JSONTokener( jsonDataObj.get("final_slots").toString()).nextValue();

                /*******************************If response (final_slots) is JsonObject******************************/
                if (json instanceof JSONObject) {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonDataObj.getJSONObject("final_slots");


                     appointmentData=new AppointmentData();
                    AppointmentSettingData appointmentSettingData=new AppointmentSettingData();
                    JsonObjResponse.getString("data");
                    User userObj=new User();
                    JSONObject userJsonData= JsonObjResponse.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("user");
                    userObj.pk=userJsonData.getInt("pk");
                    userObj.unique_id=userJsonData.getString("unique_id");
                    userObj.fk_role=userJsonData.getInt("fk_role");
                    userObj.fk_status=userJsonData.getInt("fk_status");
                    userObj.fk_hospital=userJsonData.getInt("fk_hospital");
                    userObj.fk_department=userJsonData.getInt("fk_department");
                    userObj.fk_sub_department=userJsonData.getInt("fk_sub_department");
                    userObj.user_slug=userJsonData.getString("user_slug");
                    userObj.first_name=userJsonData.getString("first_name");
                    userObj.last_name=userJsonData.getString("last_name");
                    userObj.user_name_en=userJsonData.getString("user_name_en");
                    userObj.user_name_ar=userJsonData.getString("user_name_ar");
                    userObj.username=userJsonData.getString("username");
                    userObj.password=userJsonData.getString("password");
                    userObj.email=userJsonData.getString("email");
                    userObj.contact=userJsonData.getString("contact");
                   // userObj.qualification=userJsonData.getString("qualification");
                    userObj.mobile=userJsonData.getString("mobile");
                    userObj.appointment_duration=userJsonData.getInt("appointment_duration");
                    userObj.registration_date=userJsonData.getString("registration_date");
                    userObj.activation_code=userJsonData.getString("activation_code");
                    userObj.email_verified=userJsonData.getInt("email_verified");
                    userObj.device_token=userJsonData.getString("device_token");
                    userObj.device_type=userJsonData.getString("device_type");
                    userObj.device_id=userJsonData.getString("device_id");
                    userObj.created_at=userJsonData.getString("created_at");
                    userObj.updated_at=userJsonData.getString("updated_at");
                   // userObj.created_at=userJsonData.getString("created_by");
                    userObj.updated_by=userJsonData.getInt("updated_by");
                    appointmentSettingData.setUser(userObj);
                    appointmentData.setData(appointmentSettingData);
                    int i=0;
                    List<Slots> final_slots=new ArrayList<Slots>();
                while(jsonObj.getJSONObject(""+i).has("start") && jsonObj.getJSONObject(""+i).has("end")){
                    Slots slot=new Slots();
                    slot.start=jsonObj.getJSONObject(""+i).get("start").toString();
                        slot.end=jsonObj.getJSONObject(""+i).get("end").toString();
                    final_slots.add(slot);
                    appointmentSettingData.setFinal_slots(final_slots);
                    appointmentData.setData(appointmentSettingData);
                       i++;
                    }
                    totalslots = final_slots.size();
                    totalslotLines = totalslots / 5;
                } else if (json instanceof JSONArray) {
                    /*******************************If response (final_slots) is JsonArray******************************/
                    appointmentData = gsonObj.fromJson(response, AppointmentData.class);
                    totalslots = appointmentData.data.final_slots.size();
                    totalslotLines = totalslots / 5;
                }
```

**Issue:**
when in response final_slots comes as json Object. As you can that when it final_slots is as jsonObject then I am getting inside JSON Object by the index as the name of JSON Object(i.e jsonObj.getJSONObject(""+i).get("start")). I am having issue when index is missing (you can see response upload image), because i am getting by the index, assuming that index will not miss in response. but I m fail here.

```
 while(jsonObj.getJSONObject(""+i).has("start") && jsonObj.getJSONObject(""+i).has("end")){
                    Slots slot=new Slots();
                    slot.start=jsonObj.getJSONObject(""+i).get("start").toString();
                        slot.end=jsonObj.getJSONObject(""+i).get("end").toString();
                    final_slots.add(slot);
                    appointmentSettingData.setFinal_slots(final_slots);
                    appointmentData.setData(appointmentSettingData);
                       i++;
                    }
```

**what I need:**
I want to **appointmentData** object a compelete object which provide me all response either jsonArray in response or JSonobject in response.
I will be thankful to you for my assistance.

Comment: Are you getting any exception when the type changes?

Comment: @ Haresh Chaudhary when final_slots comes as jsonObject and some index is missing in response as you can see in image upload that index 3 is missing then i got issue